# VueJs Element select list with mapGetter not working

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, getter

I'm trying to implement a el-select list using data from a mapGetter. Basically the values are showing but I'm not able to select them. When I click on the option it doesn't get selected.
Here's the code

```
        <el-select v-model="value" placeholder="unassigned">
          <el-option
            v-for="item in getTeamMembers"
            :label="item.data.attributes.value"
            :value="item.id">
          </el-option>
        </el-select>
```

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: There's not enough detail to reproduce the problem. Please provide a [demo link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue).

Answer (score 0):

I think el-select is not watching changes, to make it watch you should assign a variable in your data object or state here is the demo in [codepen](https://codepen.io/elvaleryn/pen/OJMooMd)

Here is the code:

```js
<div id="app">
<template>
      <el-select 
            v-model="someVal" 
            placeholder="something"     
        >
        <el-option
            v-for="(item,index) in getTeamMembers"
            :key="index"
            :label="item.data.attributes.value"
            :value="item.id">
     </el-option>
  </el-select>
</template>
</div>
```

and data object should be:

```js
    data() {
      return {
        getTeamMembers: [
            {id: 1, data: { attributes: { value: 'vue'}}}, 
            {id: 2, data: { attributes: { value: 'laravel'}}}, 
            {id: 3, data: { attributes: { value: 'nodejs'}}}
        ],
        someVal: undefined
      }
    }
```